# App, deployed on github pages, sends GET for assets to wrong address

Tags: angular, deployment, updates, assets, github-pages

I have built my app using:

```
ng build --prod --base-href https://3hdw.github.io/zpi-frontend/
```

I noticed that deployed app doesn't load some images. 

Properly loaded images are obtained by GET sent to this address: `https://3hdw.github.io/zpi-frontend/assets/fileName`

and for some reason app tries to load other images using wrong address: `https://3hdw.github.io/assets/fileName`, which results in not loading some assets.

I noticed this behaviour after updating my angular project.

EDIT:

Not loaded images are specified with css:   `background-image: url("/assets/fileName");`
Loaded images are specified with html: `<img src="assets/fileName"/>`

after changing `url("/assets/fileName")` to `url("/zpi-frontend/assets/fileName")` images are being loaded but there should be better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--deployUrl` when running the `ng build` command. That will set the assets prefix.

Comment: Didn't work, I tried it like this: `ng build --prod --base-href https://3hdw.github.io/zpi-frontend/ --deploy-url https://3hdw.github.io/zpi-frontend/
`